# Changing an url in an image tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, request

I try to set an image from an url, which I get from a json request, which includes the size of the image. How do set the image to the right place and which requests do I need when the data type is .png?

This is for monitors of different rooms which persons are in and which statuses they have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's a "json request"? Do you mean the response to an AJAX request? Just extract the URL from the JSON and assign it to `image.src`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide some of the code that you have tired?